# Mail is sent but does not echo back "mail sent successfully" in other browsers

Tags: php, ajax, email

I'm both new to Stack overflow and to PHP - I'm having some trouble with a contact form. It is using the Mail function and I DO receive the emails once the user has submitted the form. However, for some reason the "Message has been sent" statement after the form is submitted only appears on Firefox and not on Chrome or Safari. Why is that? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$the_blogname   = 'blog's name';
$the_myemail    = 'my email';


if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    error_reporting(0); 
    $errorC = false;

    $the_email      = $_POST['email'];
    $the_name       = $_POST['yourname'];
    $the_message    = $_POST['message'];

    $the_phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $the_fax        = $_POST['fax'];
    $the_company    = $_POST['company'];
    $the_website    = $_POST['website'];

    # want to add aditional fields? just add them to the form in template_contact.php,
    # you dont have to edit this file

    //added fields that are not set explicit like the once above are combined and added before the actual message
    $already_used = array('email','yourname','message','phone','fax','company','website','myblogname','tempcode','temp_url','ajax');
    $attach = '';

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $field)
    {
        if(!in_array($key,$already_used))
        {
            $attach.= $key.": ".$field."<br /> \n";
        }
    }
    $attach.= "<br /> \n";

    if(!checkmymail($the_email))
    {
        $errorC = true;
        $the_emailclass = "error";
    }else{
        $the_emailclass = "valid";
        }

    if($the_message == "")
    {
        $errorC = true;
        $the_messageclass = "error";
    }else{
        $the_messageclass = "valid";
        }

    if($errorC == false)
    {   
        $to      =  $the_myemail;
        $subject = "New Message from " . $the_blogname;
        $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $header .= 'From:'. $the_email  . " \r\n";

        $message1 = nl2br($the_message);

        if(!empty($the_name))       $the_name   = "Name:    $the_name <br/>";
        if(!empty($the_company))    $the_company    = "Company: $the_company <br/>";
        if(!empty($the_phone))      $the_phone      = "Phone:   $the_phone <br/>";
        if(!empty($the_fax))        $the_fax    = "Fax:     $the_fax <br/>";
        if(!empty($the_website))    $the_website    = "Website: $the_website <br/>";

        $message = "
        You have a new message! <br/>
        $the_name
        $the_company
        $the_phone
        $the_website

        $attach <br />

        Message: $message1 <br />";


        if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$header)) $send = true; else $send = false;

        if(isset($_POST['ajax']))

        if ($send)
        echo '<h3>Your message has been sent!</h3><div class="confirm">
                <p class="textconfirm">Thank you for contacting us.<br/>We will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
              </div>';
        else
        echo '<h3>Oops!</h3><div class="confirm">
                <p class="texterror">Due to an unknown error, your form was not submitted, please resubmit it or try later.</p>
              </div>'; 


        }
    }




function checkmymail($mailadresse){
$email_flag=preg_match("!^\w[\w|\.|\-]+@\w[\w|\.|\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$!",$mailadresse);
return $email_flag;
}

?>
```

**Here's the JS (just in case):**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
tfuse_custom_form();
});

function tfuse_custom_form(){ 
var my_error;
var url = jQuery("input[name=temp_url]").attr('value');
jQuery("#send").bind("click", function(){

my_error = false;
jQuery(".ajax_form input, .ajax_form textarea, .ajax_form radio, .ajax_form     select").each(function(i)
{
            var surrounding_element = jQuery(this);
            var value               = jQuery(this).attr("value"); 
            var check_for           = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            var required            = jQuery(this).hasClass("required"); 

            if(check_for == "email"){
                surrounding_element.removeClass("error valid");
                baseclases = surrounding_element.attr("class");
                if(!value.match(/^\w[\w|\.|\-]+@\w[\w|\.|\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)){
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("error");
                    my_error = true;
                }else{
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("valid"); 
                }
            }

            if(check_for == "message"){
                surrounding_element.removeClass("error valid");
                baseclases = surrounding_element.attr("class");
                if(value == "" || value == "Write your message..."){                    
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("error");
                    my_error = true;
                }else{
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("valid"); 
                }
            }

            if(required && check_for != "email" && check_for != "message"){
                surrounding_element.removeClass("error valid");
                baseclases = surrounding_element.attr("class");
                if(value == ""){                    
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("error");
                    my_error = true;
                }else{
                    surrounding_element.attr("class",baseclases).addClass("valid"); 
                }
            }


           if(jQuery(".ajax_form input, .ajax_form textarea, .ajax_form radio, .ajax_form select").length  == i+1){ 
                if(my_error == false){
                    jQuery(".ajax_form").slideUp(400);

                    var $datastring = "ajax=true";
                    jQuery(".ajax_form input, .ajax_form textarea, .ajax_form radio, .ajax_form select").each(function(i)
                    {
                        var $name = jQuery(this).attr('name');  
                        var $value = encodeURIComponent(jQuery(this).attr('value'));
                        $datastring = $datastring + "&" + $name + "=" + $value;
                    });


                    jQuery(".ajax_form #send").fadeOut(100);    

                    jQuery.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: url+"/sendmail.php",
                       data: $datastring,
                       success: function(response){
                       jQuery(".ajax_form").before("<div class='ajaxresponse' style='display: none;'></div>");
                       jQuery(".ajaxresponse").html(response).slideDown(400); 
                       jQuery(".ajax_form #send").fadeIn(400);
                       jQuery(".ajax_form input, .ajax_form textarea, .ajax_form radio, .ajax_form select").val("");
                           }
                        });
                    } 
            }

        });
        return false;
});
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a CSS or HTML problem, not a PHP problem. Can you post your HTML and style sheets? Also, you tagged this [tag:ajax], but there is no javascript in your code; please post any relevant javascript.

Comment: This line `$attach.= "<br /> \n";` could be changed to `$attach.= "<br />" . "\n";` which may be "one" issue. Plus this line `$the_blogname   = 'blog's name';` may also pose a problem. Escape it `$the_blogname   = 'blog\'s name';`

Comment: You have a quotes problem in your first line: `$the_blogname   = 'blog's name';`

Comment: I changed the `$attach.= "<br /> \n";` to `$attach.= "<br />" . "\n";` Perhaps that's more correct. But unfortunately there was no change. The echoed message still did not appear. The `$the_blogname = 'blog's name;'` variable was just a placeholder. Here's the actual site so you can check out the HTML and CSS with firebug: http://www.myvisionsinglass.com

Comment: in the actual code it reads like so - `$the_blogname = 'Visions in Glass';`

Comment: I looked at your source and CSS files as much as I could, and did not find anything (class) related to `class="confirm"` and `class="texterror"` so that could be "a" fault. Cool site though ;-)

Comment: You're right. I just did a search in the actual css file and there weren't any classes with those names. So I just removed those divs and classes all together. It appears like so:

Comment: `if ($send)
   echo '<h3>Your message has been sent!</h3>Thank you for contacting us.<br/>We will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>';
   else
   echo '<h3>Oops!</h3>Due to an unknown error, your form was not submitted, please resubmit it or try later.</p>';`

Comment: Unfortunately, still no fix on Chrome or Safari. Could this perhaps be a server-side issue?

Comment: If you're using Ajax, from what I've seen here `$_POST['ajax']` then that "could" be an issue, could be JS, Lordie... could be anything. I don't have Chrome or Safari, so I can't test any further.

Comment: I doubt it's server-side. The "server" is doing its job. It's usually client-side that stands to be the culprit.

Comment: ok, I do appreciate all your help Fred! Thank you!

Comment: Something that could be at play here, would be the missing `{}` for your `if` conditions. May not even be that, but I always use braces for conditionals myself, just to be on the safe side.